# Running a .py code from Command Line Argument, using Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I have prepared a Python script which reads from Excel files:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import StringIO
import sys
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook

filelocation = str(sys.argv[0])
outputlocation = str(sys.argv[1])
FileExtension = str(sys.argv[2])
Separator = str(sys.argv[3])



#filelocation = 'C:\Desktop\MasterFile.xlsx'
#outputlocation = 'C:\Desktop\output'
wb = open_workbook(filelocation)
```

If I execute it through Jupyter Notebook, it executes successfully.

But when I run it from the command line by passing the below parameters it gives me an error

**Command Line:**

```
python MergeFilesv1_2.py "C:\Desktop\MasterFile.xlsx" "C:\Desktop\output" ".csv" ","
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MergeFilesv1_2.py",line 22, in <module>
wb = open_workbook(filelocation)
File "C:\Users\Sha\appData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\xlrd\_init__.py",line 441, in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "C:\Users\Sha\appData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",line 91, in open_workbook_xls
biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
File "C:\Users\Sha\appData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",line 1230, in getbof
bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' %SELF.MEM[SAVPOS:SAVPOS + 8])
File "C:\Users\Sha\appData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py",line 1224, in bof_error
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file:' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError:Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record, found '\n# codin'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file's name is also an argument.

Which means,
`sys.argv[0]` is assigned as `MergeFilesv1_2.py`,
`sys.argv[1]` is assigned as `"C:\Desktop\MasterFile.xlsx"` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Lafexlos. Dont know how i miss that.

Comment: @SachinKamble To be a responsible member of the Stack Overflow community, please mark the answer given above as the correct answer and upvote it. For more explanation, please read the link given in the previous comment.

Comment: @JonathanMarch Actually my reputation is less then 15 hence i cannot do that

Comment: Just fixed that! :)